# error: 'png_destroy_write_struct' was not declared in this scope

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-ndk

[image]

I am trying to integrate **cocos2dx version 2.1.2** in my eclipse(OS - Linux version - 13.10).I am using **android-ndk-r8e**. I have followed each and every step mention in below tutorial :-

http://www.raywenderlich.com/33750/cocos2d-x-tutorial-for-ios-and-android-getting-started

- I have provided correct path on android ndk and android sdk to my `.bashrc` and to my `create-android-project.sh` script as well as to `build_native.sh`(only android ndk root path).
- I have also installed `libpng12-dev` too. I have placed the whole content of prebuilt folder in my *jni* folder of project( folders that i have pasted are -: `libcurl`, `libjpeg`, `libpng`, `libtiff`, `libwebp`, `libxml2` ).
- I have also added following lines to my `Application.mk`.

  `APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a`

  `APP_PLATFORM := android-8`
- Also Changed the line in `android.mk` :

  From

  `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES :=$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes`

  To

  `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES :=/$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes \$(LOCAL_PATH)/include`

But whenever I run `./build_native.sh` command i got the following issues:-

```html
y/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2032:1: error: 'PNG_EXPORT' does not name a type
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2036:1: error: 'PNG_EXPORT' does not name a type
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2040:1: error: 'PNG_EXPORT' does not name a type
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2044:1: error: 'PNG_EXPORT' does not name a type
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2048:1: error: 'PNG_EXPORT' does not name a type
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2052:1: error: 'PNG_EXPORT' does not name a type
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2056:1: error: 'PNG_EXPORT' does not name a type
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2058:1: error: 'PNG_EXPORT' does not name a type
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2060:1: error: 'PNG_EXPORT' does not name a type
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2064:14: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2072:1: error: 'PNG_EXPORT' does not name a type
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2074:1: error: 'PNG_EXPORT' does not name a type
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2076:1: error: 'PNG_EXPORT' does not name a type
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2083:1: error: 'PNG_EXPORT' does not name a type
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2088:1: error: 'PNG_EXPORT' does not name a type
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2093:1: error: 'PNG_EXPORT' does not name a type
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2098:14: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2165:1: error: 'PNG_EXPORT' does not name a type
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2169:1: error: 'PNG_EXPORT' does not name a type
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2174:1: error: 'PNG_EXPORT' does not name a type
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2180:1: error: 'PNG_EXPORT' does not name a type
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2186:1: error: 'PNG_EXPORT' does not name a type
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2192:1: error: 'PNG_EXPORT' does not name a type
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2199:1: error: 'PNG_EXPORT' does not name a type
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2205:1: error: 'PNG_EXPORT' does not name a type
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2211:1: error: 'PNG_EXPORT' does not name a type
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2215:1: error: 'PNG_EXPORT' does not name a type
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2218:1: error: 'PNG_EXPORT' does not name a type
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2222:1: error: 'PNG_EXPORT' does not name a type
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2227:1: error: 'PNG_EXPORT' does not name a type
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2232:1: error: 'PNG_EXPORT' does not name a type
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2237:1: error: 'PNG_EXPORT' does not name a type
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2239:1: error: 'PNG_EXPORT' does not name a type
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2244:1: error: 'PNG_EXPORT' does not name a type
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2250:1: error: 'PNG_EXPORT' does not name a type
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2256:1: error: 'PNG_EXPORT' does not name a type
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2261:1: error: 'PNG_EXPORT' does not name a type
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2267:1: error: 'PNG_EXPORT' does not name a type
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2279:1: error: 'PNG_EXPORT' does not name a type
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2284:1: error: 'PNG_EXPORT' does not name a type
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2289:1: error: 'PNG_EXPORT' does not name a type
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2294:1: error: 'PNG_EXPORT' does not name a type
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2300:1: error: 'PNG_EXPORT' does not name a type
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2306:14: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2323:14: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2432:1: error: 'PNG_EXPORT' does not name a type
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2439:1: error: 'PNG_EXPORT' does not name a type
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2444:1: error: 'PNG_EXPORT' does not name a type
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2456:1: error: 'PNG_EXPORT' does not name a type
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2459:1: error: 'PNG_EXPORT' does not name a type
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2467:1: error: 'PNG_EXPORT' does not name a type
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2473:1: error: 'PNG_EXPORT' does not name a type
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2477:1: error: 'PNG_EXPORT' does not name a type
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2482:1: error: 'PNG_EXPORT' does not name a type
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2484:1: error: 'PNG_EXPORT' does not name a type
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2486:1: error: 'PNG_EXPORT' does not name a type
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2488:1: error: 'PNG_EXPORT' does not name a type
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2492:1: error: 'PNG_EXPORT' does not name a type
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2507:1: error: 'PNG_EXPORT' does not name a type
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2513:1: error: 'PNG_EXPORT' does not name a type
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include/png.h:2515:1: error: 'PNG_EXPORT' does not name a type
In file included from /home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/android/CCImage.cpp:28:0:
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/CCImageCommon_cpp.h: In function 'void cocos2d::pngReadCallback(png_structp, png_bytep, png_size_t)':
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/CCImageCommon_cpp.h:60:66: error: 'png_get_io_ptr' was not declared in this scope
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/CCImageCommon_cpp.h:69:54: error: 'png_error' was not declared in this scope
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/CCImageCommon_cpp.h: In member function 'bool cocos2d::CCImage::_initWithPngData(void*, int)':
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/CCImageCommon_cpp.h:363:9: error: 'png_sig_cmp' was not declared in this scope
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/CCImageCommon_cpp.h:366:72: error: 'png_create_read_struct' was not declared in this scope
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/CCImageCommon_cpp.h:370:50: error: 'png_create_info_struct' was not declared in this scope
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/CCImageCommon_cpp.h:374:9: error: 'png_set_longjmp_fn' was not declared in this scope
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/CCImageCommon_cpp.h:382:63: error: 'png_set_read_fn' was not declared in this scope
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/CCImageCommon_cpp.h:387:40: error: 'png_read_info' was not declared in this scope
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/CCImageCommon_cpp.h:389:57: error: 'png_get_image_width' was not declared in this scope
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/CCImageCommon_cpp.h:390:59: error: 'png_get_image_height' was not declared in this scope
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/CCImageCommon_cpp.h:391:66: error: 'png_get_bit_depth' was not declared in this scope
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/CCImageCommon_cpp.h:392:70: error: 'png_get_color_type' was not declared in this scope
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/CCImageCommon_cpp.h:400:43: error: 'png_set_palette_to_rgb' was not declared in this scope
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/CCImageCommon_cpp.h:405:51: error: 'png_set_expand_gray_1_2_4_to_8' was not declared in this scope
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/CCImageCommon_cpp.h:408:59: error: 'png_get_valid' was not declared in this scope
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/CCImageCommon_cpp.h:410:42: error: 'png_set_tRNS_to_alpha' was not declared in this scope
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/CCImageCommon_cpp.h:415:37: error: 'png_set_strip_16' was not declared in this scope
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/CCImageCommon_cpp.h:420:40: error: 'png_set_gray_to_rgb' was not declared in this scope
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/CCImageCommon_cpp.h:429:47: error: 'png_read_update_info' was not declared in this scope
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/CCImageCommon_cpp.h:431:54: error: 'png_get_rowbytes' was not declared in this scope
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/CCImageCommon_cpp.h:440:45: error: 'png_read_image' was not declared in this scope
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/CCImageCommon_cpp.h:442:35: error: 'png_read_end' was not declared in this scope
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/CCImageCommon_cpp.h:468:72: error: 'png_destroy_read_struct' was not declared in this scope
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/CCImageCommon_cpp.h: In member function 'bool cocos2d::CCImage::_saveImageToPNG(char const*, bool)':
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/CCImageCommon_cpp.h:726:82: error: 'png_create_write_struct' was not declared in this scope
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/CCImageCommon_cpp.h:734:50: error: 'png_create_info_struct' was not declared in this scope
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/CCImageCommon_cpp.h:738:52: error: 'png_destroy_write_struct' was not declared in this scope
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/CCImageCommon_cpp.h:742:20: error: 'png_set_longjmp_fn' was not declared in this scope
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/CCImageCommon_cpp.h:745:57: error: 'png_destroy_write_struct' was not declared in this scope
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/CCImageCommon_cpp.h:749:32: error: 'png_init_io' was not declared in this scope
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/CCImageCommon_cpp.h:754:84: error: 'png_set_IHDR' was not declared in this scope
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/CCImageCommon_cpp.h:759:84: error: 'png_set_IHDR' was not declared in this scope
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/CCImageCommon_cpp.h:762:94: error: 'png_malloc' was not declared in this scope
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/CCImageCommon_cpp.h:763:72: error: 'png_set_PLTE' was not declared in this scope
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/CCImageCommon_cpp.h:765:41: error: 'png_write_info' was not declared in this scope
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/CCImageCommon_cpp.h:767:32: error: 'png_set_packing' was not declared in this scope
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/CCImageCommon_cpp.h:773:57: error: 'png_destroy_write_struct' was not declared in this scope
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/CCImageCommon_cpp.h:784:50: error: 'png_write_image' was not declared in this scope
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/CCImageCommon_cpp.h:797:65: error: 'png_destroy_write_struct' was not declared in this scope
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/CCImageCommon_cpp.h:816:54: error: 'png_write_image' was not declared in this scope
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/CCImageCommon_cpp.h:830:54: error: 'png_write_image' was not declared in this scope
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/CCImageCommon_cpp.h:837:40: error: 'png_write_end' was not declared in this scope
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/CCImageCommon_cpp.h:839:34: error: 'png_free' was not declared in this scope
/home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/CocoTestAgain/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/CCImageCommon_cpp.h:842:53: error: 'png_destroy_write_struct' was not declared in this scope
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/cocos2dx_static/platform/android/CCImage.o] Error
```

Comment: Hey,Its been 2 weeks i am trying to implement cocos2dx , i am very much new to this please provide me some clues or solutions to solve this error...I am using libpng-1.6.16 in my project (png.h , pngconf.h , pnglibconf.h , pngusr.h These all files are placed under path cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/include).

Comment: The backslash in your LOCAL_C_INCLUDES looks suspicious.

Comment: Hey Glenn, thanks for your comment but still i am getting this same error after removing the backslash from line :- LOCAL_C_INCLUDES :=$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes \$(LOCAL_PATH)/include.

Comment: You could try uninstalling libpng12-dev.  That package has older versions of png.h and pngconf.h that could be conflicting with the ones from libpng-1.6.16 (libpng16) that you also installed.

Comment: As per your suggestion i have uninstalled libpng12-dev and reinstalled libpng-1.6.16 and replaced the png.h , pnglibconf.h and pngconf.h with the .h files which i got from libpng-1.6.16 in jni(jni/libpng/include) folder of my project. But still i am getting same issue.